# difference between LinkLabel.Click and LinkLabel.LinkClicked event?

Tags: c#, winforms, events, linklabel

According to http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.linklabel.aspx, the `LinkLabel` class has both a `Click` event inherited from `System.Windows.Forms.Control` and a `LinkClicked` event.  From my understanding, `Click` event will trigger the `LinkClicked` event.

Why on earth have a `LinkClicked` event?? What's wrong with the `Click` event? Are there other ways to trigger `LinkClicked` besides clicking?

Comment: Click is inherited from Control.  You can't un-inherit base class members.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`Click` will be raised if you click anywhere in the control. `LinkClicked` will be raised only if you click on a link area. `Click` will be raised in both cases (before `LinkClicked` if you click on a link).

Comment: Also, if the `LinkLabel` has the focus and the user presses Enter, only the `LinkClicked` seemed to be called.

Answer (score 3):

The LinkClicked event has specific [LinkLabelLinkClickedEventArg](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.linklabellinkclickedeventargs.aspx) that allows you to do more than responding to the Click event, which could be fired by the user clicking anywhere on the control not just the link part.

```
private void linkLabel1_LinkClicked(object sender, LinkLabelLinkClickedEventArgs e)
{
    // Specify that the link was visited.
    this.linkLabel1.LinkVisited = true;

    var target = e.Link.LinkData as string;
    System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(target);
}
```